# How to ensure tableView.scrollTo() displays correctly when initializing the table

Tags: javafx-8

I am building a screen where the system jumps to rows in a TableView based on error conditions.  Not all rows will be touched.  My table view can hold approximately 23 rows.  When there are less details than that I have no issues.

However when there is more and the first item in error is off the visual flow, I get weird rendering on the first access only.

In this example, I have 63 rows of data, and the first row that needs to be reviewed is like 35.

When the system determines the row it needs to access I jump there by first selecting the row and then scrolling the table to it:

When I initialize the table:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
tableView.setItems(sorted);
tableView.setEditable(true);
```

In the call to select the next row:

```
int nextRow = determineNextRow();
tableView.getSelectionModel().select(nextRow, columnToEdit);
tableView.scrollTo(nextRow);
```

At this point the table scrolls off top & bottom.  And the display looks like this:

[image]

After entering the amount, it drops to the next line and everything looks OK.

[image]

I am not quite sure how to correct the initial landing.

Thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060978/javafx-tableview-scrollto-causing-wrong-row-to-start-editing

Comment: Thanks - but that didn't work for me.

Comment: same procedure as always with same initial guess: something wrong with the code you are not showing?

Comment: Not sure I understand your statement.  I select a row, scroll to it.  If the table overflows both ways and the first selection it shows half the row.  When I jump to the next row, it's fine.  I guess I am allowing cell selection - table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

Comment: hach ... forgot to name the _same procedure_ - you are long enough around to know what it is: provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem ...

Comment: Thanks - I will see if I can replicate the behavior in a simple example.  I tried  with as simple an application as I could and it rendered correctly (doing exactly the same thing)- go figure - my guess is the more complicated scene graph or something.  So I will need to add in more to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I was able to correct the behavior by updating my FXML to ensure no horizontal scrollbar appeared on the table.  Though trying this with generating the table in code without FXML didn't replicate this behavior.

Comment: glad you found a (kind-of) solution - would be helpful to others if you could post your findings as a SSCCE (you now have it :-)

Comment: I don't have a SSCCE - that worked correctly, no matter what I tried unfortunately.

Comment: hmm ... that's unfortunate, indeed. Could it be a threading issue, something like scrollTo called before the ui is fully loaded? And just to make sure that I understand what you are saying: a) you never can reproduce the issue when creating the ui by code b) when loading your production ui from fxml, having no horizontal scrollbar fixes it. Which leaves c) when loading a SSCCE ui from fxml, the issue is .. ?

Comment: Yes - I think you summed it up correctly.